# undo changes in eclipse package explorer

Tags: java, eclipse

I have unknowingly clicked on some files in package explorer in eclipse and they had been moved or deleted. I wish to undo the changes occurred in package explorer and I am not able to fin that option from *edit->undo* or by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>

Is there any way out to undo changes in tree structure or deletions from package explorer in eclipse? Please help.

Comment: Just a tip for the future: inform yourself about version-control software like git and try to use it.

Comment: If the focus is not in an editor but in the _Package Explorer_, Ctrl+Z works for me.

Answer (score 1):

With focus in the Package Explorer `Ctrl + Z` should still be what you can use.  There should also be a back arrow on the top bar (unless you removed it) which should, on hover, tell you what will be undone. Alternatively you might be able to just right click on your project and `Restore from Local History`.

Also as @M.Dan says, you should definitely use version control to help mitigate issues like this.